# Object factory with derived classes containing different member methods than base class

Tags: c++, oop, factory

So, I have some classes derived from a base class which should be created at runtime on some specific parameters for which I created a factory class

My base class is

```cpp
class PostReceptionErrorModel : public ns3::Object {

    public:
        std::string getModel() { return m_model; }
        bool isEnabled() { return m_isEnabled; }
    protected:
        std::string m_model;
        bool m_isEnabled = false;

};
```

The derived class is

```cpp
class PostReceptionRateErrorModel : public PostReceptionErrorModel {

    public:
        PostReceptionRateErrorModel(std::string model, std::string errorUnit, double errorRate, std::string ranVar);
        virtual ~PostReceptionRateErrorModel() {};
        std::string getErrorUnit() {return m_ErrorUnit;}
        double getErrorRate() {return m_ErrorRate;}
        std::string getRanVar() {return m_RanVar;}

    private:
        std::string m_ErrorUnit;
        double m_ErrorRate;
        std::string m_RanVar;
};

PostReceptionRateErrorModel::PostReceptionRateErrorModel(std::string model, std::string errorUnit, double errorRate, std::string ranVar) {
    m_model = model;
    m_ErrorUnit = errorUnit;
    m_ErrorRate = errorRate;
    m_RanVar = ranVar;
    m_isEnabled = true;
}
```

And the factory class is

```cpp
class Factory
{
    public:
        static std::shared_ptr<PostReceptionErrorModel> CreateInstance(std::string name);
};

std::shared_ptr<PostReceptionErrorModel> Factory::CreateInstance(std::string name) {

    PostReceptionErrorModel * instance = nullptr;

    if(name == "ns3::RateErrorModel") {
        instance = new PostReceptionRateErrorModel("ns3::RateErrorModel", "Test", 0.1, "test");
    }

    if(instance != nullptr) {
        return std::shared_ptr<PostReceptionErrorModel>(instance);
    } else {
        return nullptr;
    }

}
```

In the main function I create an instance of PostReceptionRateErrorModel and call getErrorUnit

```cpp
 auto RateErrorModel = Factory::CreateInstance("ns3::RateErrorModel");
    std::cout << RateErrorModel->getModel() << "\t" << RateErrorModel->getErrorUnit() << std::endl;
```

However, I get the following error message

`error: ‘using element_type = class PostReceptionErrorModel’ {aka ‘class PostReceptionErrorModel’} has no member named ‘getErrorUnit’`

As far as I can see, the shared pointer points to an instance of PostReceptionRateErrorModel. However, I don't understand why I can't call the method. What's the reason for this and is there a workaround?

Comment: *However, I don't understand why I can't call the method* -- This is a case where you're being spoiled by `auto`.  Inspect what that `auto RateErrorModel` actually reveals.  In other words, remove `auto` and actually use the full type name and get that to compile with no errors.

Comment: Your function returns a `std::shared_ptr<PostReceptionErrorModel>` which means as far as the compiler is concerned, only the functions that belong to `PostReceptionErrorModel` can be called.

Comment: You also could have simplified this [down to a simple example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c366312d1a6f650).

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, however, don't I have to return `std::shared_ptr<PostReceptionErrorModel>` because the function type is `std::shared_ptr<PostReceptionErrorModel>`? I thought the return type has to be congruent with the function type

Comment: Also, your `PostReceptionErrorModel` should have a virtual destructor.  As it stands now, it isn't meant to be derived from and is not polymorphic.

Comment: @BrainDamage Yes, you have to return a `std::shared_ptr<PostReceptionErrorModel>` 
 since a `shared_ptr<T>` and a `shared_ptr<T_derived>` are not covariant.  When you return a `std::shared_ptr<PostReceptionErrorModel>` it doesn't matter what derived class the pointer actually points to.  The interface you are using is that of a `PostReceptionErrorModel`, so you are only allowed to access the `PostReceptionErrorModel` part that the pointer points to.

Comment: @BrainDamage -- The compiler sees that you are returning type `T`, that's all that matters.  If you want to tell the compiler "this is really a U, not a T", you have to explicitly do this by casting.